# Best approach to switch actions from different controllers depending on user selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with a screen that needs to perform a payment based on the selected "**Payment Methods**" exposed with a checkbox for each one as you can see in the following mockup.

[image]
The most important thing, is that every *payment method* has its own logic based on the API that each provide to us where some of them need to redirect a URL for login on their site (i.e. PayPal), and some others only to specify some credentials and execute the payment itself. So, according with this, we have been forced to create a controller for each one in order to delegate the interaction with the user once he chose an option. Being more clearer, it will be something like this:

```
 public class PayPalController : BaseController, IPaymentController
 {
    public ActionResult Pay()
    {
        //logic for a pay with PayPal
        return View("PaymentSuccess");
    }
 }

 public class BankOfNigeriaController : BaseController, IPaymentController
 {
    public ActionResult Pay()
    {
        //logic for a pay with Bank Of Nigeria
        return View("PaymentSuccess");
    }
 }

 public class BankOfAngolaController : BaseController, IPaymentController
 {
    public ActionResult Pay()
    {
        //logic for a pay with Bank Of Angola
        return View("PaymentSuccess");
    }
 }

 public interface IPaymentController
 {
    ActionResult Pay();
 }
```

Focused on the view that I exposed on the top, I am wondering which is the best practice to call the proper action method.

***Option 1:*** consists on create a middle controller that redirects to the proper action.

**The ViewModel** has an string that it will be used for the redirect URL as selected option. In example: "PayPal" or "BankOfNigeria".

```
public class PayPalPaymentViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string PaymentSelected { get; set; }
}
```

**The View** shows a begin form that will POST to a middle controller that, according with the chosen option will perform another redirect.

```
@model Bollore.IES.Web.Models.PaymentMethodViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Payment Methods";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("RedirectPay", "PaymentMethod", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //HTML WITH LIST OF CHECKBOXES

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

**The MIDDLE Controller** receives in the ViewModel the chosen method, and redirects to their own controller. I didn't test it, at the moment is only pseudo-code.

```
 public class PaymentMethodController : BaseController
 {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RedirectPay()
    {
       //returns the view
       return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RedirectPay(PaymentMethodViewModel model)
    {
       //it could be "PayPal/Pay" or "BankOfNigeria/Pay", etc.
       return RedirectToAction("Pay", model.PaymentSelected);
    }
 }
```

***Option 2:*** consists on redirect the action directly from the client-side of the view without passing over the middle controller, which in this case, it will only exist for the GET of the view.

**The View** will be gotten by the PaymentMethodController, but the POST the the "payment method" action, will be done by javascript.

```
@model Bollore.IES.Web.Models.PaymentMethodViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Payment Methods";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
//LIST OF CHECKBOXES AND ALL THE STUFF

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Save" onclick="callPaymentMethodAction();" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function callPaymentMethodAction(e) {
         var selectedMethodUrl = GetMethodSelectedUrl(); //it will return 'PayPal', 'BankOfAngola', etc
         $.ajax({
           url: 'selectedMethodUrl',
           data: { id: id },
           success: function(){
           alert('Payed');      
         }
      });
   };
</script>
```

**I repeat that is a pseudo-code that could not compile**, but I hope you get the idea.

> So, which of this two is the best approach to deal with a problem like
>   this? How can you manage the fact to be able to call multiple
>   controllers from the view?

Comment: If your wanting to redirect to a view,then ajax does not seem appropriate (ajax calls stay on the same page). And I suspect you want radio buttons, (not checkboxes which would allow selection of more than one payment method). The value of the radio buttons would be the name of the controller (or better an enum value indicating the payment method)

Comment: exactly what you said! The view will have radio buttons instead of checkboxes... that was because is a mockup of the view. So, according to your answer you're saying that is better to use the option 1 using a Middle controller?